# How to create pdf and render content as table in Xamarin form

Tags: pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pdf-generation, pdftron

I want to create pdf in Xamarin form and want to render string data in table structure. How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Syncfusion Xamarin.Forms PDF in order to achieve your requirement

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-tables

https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/xamarin

Any further queries, contact the support

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums

Comment: Please suggest any other library.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms, you can use HTML to PDF to generate your document:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/xamarin/guides/conversion/html-to-pdf/android/
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/xamarin/guides/conversion/html-to-pdf/ios/

Comment: I want it in UWP also